# Is Min a sufficient statistic for the uniform distribution $U(0,\theta)$

Tags: statistics

Assume we have $Y_1, ..., Y_n$ iid sample from the uniform distribution $U(0,\theta)$. Assume $T(Y_1, ..., Y_n) = Min_{1<=i<=n}(Y_i)$

I was wondering how can I prove that The minimum statistic is or is not a sufficient statistic for the uniform distribution $U(0,\theta)$.

I know that I should prove that $F_{Y_1,...,Y_n|T}(y|t)$ is independent of parameter $\theta$ if I want to show sufficiency but I can't find this conditional distribution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you mean sufficient for the parameter $\theta,$ then perhaps you mean the maximum rather than the minimum?  (your question still applies even if it's "minimum" but it feels awkward since the minimum provides essentially no information about $\theta$ for large data sets)

Answer (score 1):

Using the Fisher-Neyman factorization theorem, [we may see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Uniform_distribution) that the minimum is sufficient for $\theta$ if and only if the indicator function $\mathbf{1}(\max Y_i < \theta)$ can be factored $f(Y) g_\theta(\min Y_i).$  It's not hard to see that $f$ cannot be zero, so in particular, this shows
$$\max Y_i \geq \theta \iff g_\theta(\min Y_i) = 0$$
Since $\max Y_i$ can't be determined from $\min Y_i,$ no such function $g_\theta$ exists.

This last line isn't a formal proof, but it's a good reason to doubt the sufficiency of the minimum.